# php login system using crypt and json_encoded data

Tags: php, json, crypt

I just moved servers to a unix server and my login code no longer works.

When the data from the registration form is valid (from a jquery perspective), I pass the data from the form to the processing script like this:

```
if ($("#register_form").valid()) {
    var data1 = $('#register_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_register.php",
        data: data1,
        dataType: 'json'
         ........
```

In process_register, this is how I store the password:

```
$Salt = uniqid(); 
$Algo = '6'; 
$Rounds = '5000'; 
$CryptSalt = '$' . $Algo . '$rounds=' . $Rounds . '$' . $Salt;
$hashed_password = crypt($password, $CryptSalt);
```

When the user tries to login, I again pass the data via json_encode:

```
        var data1 = $('#login_form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_login.php",
            data: data1,
            dataType: 'json',
            .............
```

And then I compare the two passwords:

```
if (crypt($user_password, $passwd_from_db) == $passwd_from_db) {
   // passwords match
```

But the passwords never match.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm running php 5.3 on Unix server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a careful look at the [manual page for crypt()](http://php.net/crypt). You're omitting the second parameter:

> `salt` An optional salt string to base the hashing on. **If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and
>   can lead to unexpected results**.

The salt is used to choose the hash algorithm. If you don't choose one yourself you use the server default. When server changes, default changes.

---

```
$hashed_password = utf8_encode(crypt($password));
```

Er... Sorry but hashes are not plain text. You shouldn't handle them as such.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I edited my question above to include a salt I generate, but it still does not work.

Comment: Are you matching *old* passwords?

Comment: No.  However, the problem is with the crypt function.  When I print out the value of crypt($user_password, $db_hash) , it prints out as '', even though $user_password, and $db_hash print out correctly.  Why would crypt return nothing?

Comment: What does `var_dump(crypt($user_password, $db_hash))` print?

Comment: It prints out a blank line!  Just above that, I print out $user_password (which is correct), and $db_hash(which is correct).  I cut and pasted the variables to make sure no typos.  I"m mystified.

Comment: When I do this though: `$crypt=crypt($user_password, $db_hash);
        error_log("crypt is " . $crypt);` I still get a different hash than what is stored in the db!

Comment: Blank line? Did you use `var_dump` or just `echo`?

Comment: `error_log(var_dump(crypt($password, $db_password)));`   prints a blank line

Comment: Please `var_dump(crypt($user_password, $db_hash));`. Just `var_dump(crypt($user_password, $db_hash))` and nothing else. Especifially, remove `error_log()`.

Comment: `var_dump()` always prints something, unless PHP is segfaulting or something as bad as that. One way to know if PHP is crashing is to add some `echo 'not crashed';` right after `var_dump()`. That'd be really bad news anyway—random PHP core crashes have never an easy fix (except upgrading PHP).

Comment: echo'd not crashed just after vardump and I do not even see that. However, I sent a message to error_log after the vardump and I do see that.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry my answer didn't help but, at this point, I'm simply out of new ideas.